# Hacer print en la misma línea letra por letra

Tags: python, print

Necesito que mi programa por ejemplo muestre en la pantalla "Hola mundo", pero que primero muestre la "H" , luego la "o" y así letra por letra **en la misma línea**.

Intenté usando:

```py
a = "Hola mundo"
from time import sleep
for i in a:
    print (i, end="")
    sleep(0.2)
```

Pero el tiempo de espera se acumula para cada letra y me muestra todo de una vez.

Comment: si es python 3 deberia funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solamente tienes que añadir `flush=True` en el `print`

```
print (i, end="", flush=True)
```

básicamente es almacenado la cadena en un beffered hasta el nuevo salto del linea, por eso si quitas el `end=""` igual funciona. Con el flash se intenta forzar a que imprima siempre.